# After CSS inline content

Tags: html, css

I've built a list navigation and wanted to add a '*' between each list item implementing the CSS rather than the HTML. What I've currently built is:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href=''>List item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=''>List item 2</a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Obviously this builds

1. List item 1
2. List item 2

In CSS I've written:

```
ol{
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
ol>li{
   float:left;
}
ol>li>a{
   display:block;
   padding:2px 7px;
}
```

This builds:

List item 1    List item 2

JSFiddle of what currently happens: http://jsfiddle.net/v7eG7/

My question is how can I add the '*' symbol to the content of the document using `after` but keeping the list items and the afters in line with each other?

List item 1   *   List item 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you tried `ol>li:after {content:'*';}` or similar, the problem is that you set `display:block` on your `a` elements, which will force that `*` onto a line below it.

Consider changing the `a`'s `display:block` to `display:inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add:

```
ol > li:after {
    content: "*";   
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

And change:

```
ol > li > a {
    display:block;
}
```

To:

```
ol > li > a {
    display:inline;
}
```

Here is a demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7eG7/1/)

And if you would like the last element without the `*`, you will have to add:

```
ol > li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7eG7/2/)